# Why is my download speed higher than my bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-networking, speed

iperf3 reports my bandwidth between my laptop and router (openWRT) over WiFi to be **24.2** Mbits/sec. But when I run speedtest on my laptop I get download speed at **49.58** Mbps and upload **35.61** Mbps which are higher than my total bandwidth.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a bug, you could [report it to iperf3](https://iperf.fr/contact.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iperf3 does a circuit of : *computer -> router -> computer*.

The result is that the bandwidth you measure is the time to make the route between
your computer and the router *two times*.

As you can see, 24.2 Mbps is just about half of 49.58 Mbps.
The numbers would never be very precise when calculated,
but there are too many parameters to take into account to fully analyze them.

Comment: To add to this, WiFi will typically be half-duplex. You cannot use the same bandwidth twice after all. If ethernet had been used then most often it operates in full-duplex (I.e. has separate transmit and receive channels, but can be configured for half-duplex) and so you get full bandwidth in both directions. WiFi uses the *same* channel for both transmit and receive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, iperf doc says "round trip time" but then I don't understand why when I plug the wire, I get 941 Mbits/sec with Gigabit ethernet. Does that mean that the actual bandwith is twice as much ?

Comment: @Mokubai has just explained the reason even before you asked : the difference between full-duplex and half-duplex.

Comment: Thanks Mokubai and harrymc, I'll dig into that

Comment: Bandwidth is "amount of data that can be moved per unit of time". The bandwidth per data path is the same for gigabit (941Mbit) but you have a path out and path in (full duplex). For WiFi you have only one path that is shared for both data going out *and* coming in. I think newer MIMO WiFi standards might effectively work in full duplex but I am not certain. The bandwidth figure is not "twice as much" for gigabit, it is just that you have more effective paths you can use at once.

Comment: See [Wikipedia Duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)).